# Can't get webvisor messages on react-yandex-metrika

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, yandex-metrika

My App.js

```js
import {YMInitializer} from 'react-yandex-metrika';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className='main'>
            <YMInitializer accounts={[XXXXXXXX]} options={{webvisor: true}} />
        </div>
           
          )
      }
      
  export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

my other component Form.js where onClick I am sending information to yandex webvisor

```js
import ym from 'react-yandex-metrika';


 ym(XXXXXXXX,'reachGoal','xxxxxxxx-form');
```

I am not getting anything do I have some syntax error or something I searched Internet and seems like everything is fine, but I still don't get webvisor messages